# how to call a web service in android

Tags: android, web-services

i need to call a web service from the url. wen i entered the no in the text box i should the output which i entered in text box. pls help me fixing the errors.  here is my java code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;

    String editText;
    String displayText;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {

                    editText = et.getText().toString();

                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();

                    task.execute();

                } else {
                    tv.setText("Please enter number");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            displayText = ser.invokeiop(editText,"hello");
            return null;

        }

    }
}
```

**ser.java**

```
public class ser {

    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static String URL = "http://my url";

    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "srvice";

    public static String invokeiop(String name, String webMethName) {
        String resTxt = null;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

        PropertyInfo iop = new PropertyInfo();

        iop.setName("name");

        iop.setValue(name);

        //iop.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(iop);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

            resTxt = response.toString();



        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


            resTxt = "Error occured";
        }
```

Comment: what you are trying to say??? do you need to pass value in web service and wanna fetch or other?

Comment: yes..pls help. am new for android. dnt knw how to do

Comment: have to pass value in web service and i should fetch from it

Comment: No.. trying with SOAP only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you!!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b;
EditText et;

String editText;
String displayText;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {

                editText = et.getText().toString();

                AsyncCallWS();

            } else {
                // declare a toast
            }
        }
    });
}


public void AsyncCallWS(final String q)
{
class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    String txtSearch = params[0];
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("URL"+editText);
    try 
    {

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

    String bufferedStrChunk = null;

    while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        strB.append(bufferedStrChunk);
    }

    return strB.toString();

    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException cpe)
    {
    cpe.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }

            @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)     
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {

            // Parse your data here             
            } 
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
    }

    }
    HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask();

    httpGetAsyncTask.execute(editText);         
}
```

Comment: but when i tried this code its force closed in emulator.